# VSTO OneClick Add Trusted Publisher

Tags: vsto, one-click-web-publishing

I am working on a Excel Document Customization VSTO application.  I'm trying to make the installation as seamless as possible for the end users.  I'm noticing that they can not use my application unless they save the spreadsheet to one of their trusted folder locations.  Is there any way to prompt the user during the OneClick install to add my Certificate to their Trusted Publishers store instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those are two different issues. Adding the certificate to the list of trusted publishers only governs whether users are prompted to install the add-in. Adding entries to the list of trusted folders governs from which folders your documents can be opened.

Comment: Hi Chris, I was under the impression that if the publisher was trusted that the trusted locations did not apply, is that not the case?  Is there no way to prompt the users to trust all locations during install?  I'm afraid we will lose a lot of adoption if this manual step is required in order to make this work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is not the case. No, there is no way to trust all locations, but you could use a different type of installer. I've heard of people using an MSI installer, but I don't know much about it personally. You could use any installer framework, and just call VSTOInstaller.exe to install the add-in itself.